# Trying to get the sum of squares

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello So I am able to get the squares of my numbers but I am having trouble starting the second process where i get the some of that. I am a beginner so is there a beginner way to do this?

```
def summation_of_squares(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i**2)
    print(sum = n)
summation_of_squares(5)
```

Comment: You don't assign a value to variable in `print`

Comment: i realized that after I ran the code. do I do sum = n + i?

Comment: @pwnd16, if you need the sum of squares, you need not add `n` to your `sum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the built-in functions from here [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

```
def summation_of_squares(n):
    return sum([i**2 for i in range(1, n+1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def summation_of_squares(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        # here you need to store the sum
        sum = sum + i**2
        print(i**2)
    print(sum)

summation_of_squares(5)
```

[see how to solve it O(1)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58460/sum-of-squares-square-of-sum-difference)

Comment: The formula is what should be used. Thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: Glad! it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way of summing terms:

```
def summation_of_squares(n):
    sum=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print (i**2)
        sum+=(i**2)
    print (sum)
summation_of_squares(5)
```

PS   I have written this code assuming that you are having trouble in getting the sum of the squared numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you are only printing the square of each number and incorrectly setting the sum to n. Rather you should be incrementing the sum. Like this -

```
def summation_of_squares(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sum = sum + i**2
    print(sum)
summation_of_squares(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def summation_of_squares(n):
sumsquares = 0
for i in range(1, n+1):
    sumsquares = sumsquares + i**2
print(sumsquares)
```

summation_of_squares(5)

Okay i was messing around a little bit and with your help I got it. Before it kept giving me 1, 5, 13,30,55 but that was because i had print(sumsquares) indented

Answer (score 0):

using map and lambda functions

```
def summation_of_squares(n):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x**2,range(n+1))
```

another way.